# Sync_to_async wrapper best practice question

Tags: python, django, asynchronous, python-asyncio

So I'm building a python async program using Djang framework and I'm having some doubts about if I am correctly using the `sync_to_async` and `database_sync_to_async` functions. I'm applying them to all my I/O bound operations such as databases accesses and external API requests. However I noticed that I was also applying that wrapper to some sync functions that I do not know if they require it. some examples include functions where I only manipulate small lists and dictionaries and where I convert in memory objects to JSON to return as response. Examples:

```
class Store(object):

def __init__(self, employee, promotional):
    self.employee = employee
    self.promotional = promotional

def to_dict(self):
  return {"employee": self.employee, "promotional": self.promotional}

def store_emplyee_rate(employee_details, currency):
    if CURRENCIES[currency]["valid"]:
       employee_details["conversion_rate"] = "test"
```

```
def convert_situation(
    value, currency, conversion_rate=None, use_decimal=False, use_int_64=False
):
    if value == 0:
        if use_decimal:
            return Decimal(value)
        return value
    elif CURRENCIES[currency]["valid"]:
        value = Decimal(value) / 100

        if conversion_rate:
            value = value * Decimal(conversion_rate)
        
        return value
    else:
        if use_decimal:
            return Decimal(value) / pow(10, CURRENCIES[currency]["decimals"])
        if use_int_64:
            return value * 1000

        return value
```

Do I need to wrap this functions with `sync_to_async` calls or is that context switching uneccessary in these and similar cases? My app runs through ASGI and Uvicorn.

Comment: There is nothing async in `convert_situation`, so there's no need to wrap it either – it'll probably only make it slower.